# Fill Gaps in time series pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, pandas-resample

I have a pandas dataframe with gaps in time series.
It looks like the following:

Example Input

```
--------------------------------------
     Timestamp        Close
 2021-02-07 09:30:00  124.624 
 2021-02-07 09:31:00  124.617
 2021-02-07 10:04:00  123.946
 2021-02-07 16:00:00  123.300
 2021-02-09 09:04:00  125.746
 2021-02-09 09:05:00  125.646
 2021-02-09 15:58:00  125.235
 2021-02-09 15:59:00  126.987
 2021-02-09 16:00:00  127.124
```

Desired Output

```
--------------------------------------------
     Timestamp        Close
 2021-02-07 09:30:00  124.624 
 2021-02-07 09:31:00  124.617
 2021-02-07 09:32:00  124.617
 2021-02-07 09:33:00  124.617
   'Insert a line for each minute up to the next available
   timestamp with the Close value form the last available timestamp'
 2021-02-07 10:03:00  124.617 
 2021-02-07 10:04:00  123.946
 2021-02-07 16:00:00  123.300
   'I dont want lines inserted here. As this date is not
   present in the original dataset (could be a non trading
   day so I dont want to fill this gap)'
 2021-02-09 09:04:00  125.746
 2021-02-09 09:05:00  125.646
 2021-02-09 15:58:00  125.235
   'Fill the gaps here again but only between 09:30 and 16:00 time'
 2021-02-09 15:59:00  126.987
 2021-02-09 16:00:00  127.124
```

What I have tried is:

```
'# set the index column'
df_process.set_index('Exchange DateTime', inplace=True)

'# resample and forward fill the gaps'
df_process_out = df_process.resample(rule='1T').ffill()

'# filter and return only timestamps between 09:30 and 16:00'
df_process_out = df_process_out.between_time(start_time='09:30:00', end_time='16:00:00')
```

However if I do it like this it also resamples and generates new timestamps on dates that are not existent in the original dataframe. In the example above it would also generate timestamps on a minute basis for *2021-02-**08***

How can I avoid this?

Furthermore is there a better way to avoid resampling over the whole time.

```
df_process_out = df_process.resample(rule='1T').ffill()
```

This generates timestamps from 00:00 to 24:00 and in the next line of code I have to filter most timestamps out again.
Doesn't seem efficient.

Any help/guidance would be highly appreciated
Thanks

---

Edit:
As requested a small sample set

df_in: Input data
df_out_error: Wrong Output Data
df_out_OK: How the output data should look like

In the following ColabNotebook I prepeared a small sample.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Fps2obTv1YPDpTzXTo7ivLI5njoI-y4n?usp=sharing

Notice that this is only a small subset of the data.
I'm trying to clean multiple years of data that is structured and shows missing minutes timestamps like this.

Comment: Kindly create a small reproducible dataframe with a complete expected output dataframe

Comment: Any reason why you dont want rows inserted between ` 2021-02-07 10:04:00` and `2021-02-07 16:00:00`? or is that supposed to be filled for each minute too?

Comment: Sorry for beeing unclear. Yes this should also be filled with 1 Minute (or other Intervall) timestamps.

Comment: Please test the code I mention below. that should solve your problem.

Comment: it should solve both the concerns you have, resampling for limited time period, AND applying resample over existing dates only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve what you need with a combination of `df.groupby()` (over dates) and resampling using `rule = "1Min"`. Try this -

```
df_new = (df.assign(date=df.Timestamp.dt.date)   #create new col 'date' from the timestamp
            .set_index('Timestamp')              #set timestamp as index
            .groupby('date')                     #groupby for each date
            .apply(lambda x: x.resample('1Min')  #apply resampling for 1 minute from start time to end time for that date
                   .ffill())                     #ffill values
            .reset_index('date', drop=True)      #drop index 'date' that was created by groupby
            .drop('date',1)                      #drop 'date' column created before
            .reset_index()                       #reset index to get back original 2 cols
         )

df_new
```

[image]

---

## Explanation

#### 1. Resampling for limited time period only

> "Furthermore is there a better way to avoid resampling over the whole time. This generates timestamps from 00:00 to 24:00 and in the next line of code I have to filter most timestamps out again. Doesn't seem efficient."

As in the above solution, you can resample and then `ffill` (or any other type of fill) using rule = `1Min`. This ensures that you are not resampling from 00:00 to 24:00 but only from the start to end time stamps available in your data. To prove, I show this applied to a single date in the data -

```
#filtering for a single day
ddd = df[df['date']==df.date.unique()[0]]

#applying resampling on that given day
ddd.set_index('Timestamp').resample('1Min').ffill()
```

[image]

Notice the start (09:30:00) and end (16:00:00) timestamps for the given date.

#### 2. Applying resample over existing dates only

> "In the example above it would also generate timestamps on a minute basis for 2021-02-08. How can I avoid this?"

As in the above solution, you can apply the resampling method over date groups separately. In this case, I apply the method using a lambda function after separating out the date from the timestamps. So the resample happens only for the date that **exist in the dataset**

```
df_new.Timestamp.dt.date.unique()
```

```
array([datetime.date(2021, 2, 7), datetime.date(2021, 2, 9)], dtype=object)
```

Notice, that the output only contains the 2 unique dates from the original dataset.

Comment: Thank you this was a very good explanation!